# What's wrong with that AFTER DELETE TRIGGER?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, oracle12c

I'm trying to use a trigger to clean some `@OneToOne` related entities upon deletion of another (via SQL). Let's suppose I have a `Person` and an `OrgUnit` both referencing some `Address`. That `Address` is mapped with an `ADDRESS_ID` and related foreign key constraints.

The following trigger compiles just fine:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ON_DELETE_PERSON
AFTER DELETE ON PERSON
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM ADDRESS WHERE ID = :OLD.ADDRESS_ID;
END;
/
```

But whenever I try to delete a `Person` the following error is thrown:

```
DELETE FROM PERSON WHERE ID = 21179
```

```
ORA-04091: table MY_SCHEMA.PERSON is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: in "MY_SCHEMA.ON_DELETE_PERSON", row 2
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'MY_SCHEMA.ON_DELETE_PERSON'
```

**What must be changed to make this trigger work?**

Within the Java code I could simply handle this with `CascadeStyle.DELETE`... but I want to transfer that responsibility to the database to allow proper `ON DELETE CASCADE` behavior for all the data.

```
-- CASCADE DELETE on ORGUNIT deletion...
ALTER TABLE PERSON ADD CONSTRAINT PERSON_F01
FOREIGN KEY (ORGUNIT_ID) REFERENCES ORGUNIT (ID)
ON DELETE CASCADE ENABLE VALIDATE;

-- SET NULL on ADDRESS deletion...
ALTER TABLE PERSON ADD CONSTRAINT PERSON_F02
FOREIGN KEY (ADDRESS_ID) REFERENCES ADDRESS (ID)
ON DELETE SET NULL ENABLE VALIDATE;
```

So, deleting an `ORGUNIT` automatically deletes all related `PERSON` too... but the `ADDRESS` would remain in the database. The TRIGGER above is meant to handle this case.

Comment: If my `ADDRESS` would hold the `PERSON_ID` (mapped the other way) I could use `ON DELETE CASCADE` on that foreign key constraint. But the mapping is the other way right now. The `ADDRESS` is just an example entity that in fact is referenced from many more tables in a similar way. I don't want to reverse all those mappings.

Comment: My guess is that there's a trigger on the address table that's doing something to the person table. Is there?

Comment: No, there's no such trigger on `ADDRESS`.

Comment: ...but may that `ON DELETE SET NULL` of `PERSON_F02` be the problem here?

Comment: Yes... it is. Damn... so I can't have both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a few comments the answer pops up:

The FK constraint with `ON DELETE SET NULL` fires back to the table and causes that exception. Looks like I can't have both...

I'll get rid of the `ON DELETE` definition and risk the FK constraint error in that case. The cascaded delete via the trigger has the higher value to me.